# Adding brand that is not exists in the group of array

Tags: php, arrays

Sorry for my bad english, but here my question.

I have a array of brands

```
$brands = ['LENOVO', 'IPHONE', 'SAMSUNG'];
```

This is the list coming from the query.

```
$list = [
        {"name": "rizal",  "brand": "LENOVO"},
        {"name": "luna",   "brand": "IPHONE"},
]
```

What I want is like this

```
$list = [
        {"name": "rizal",  "brand": "LENOVO"},
        {"name": "rizal",  "brand": "IPHONE"},
        {"name": "rizal",  "brand": "SAMSUNG"},
        {"name": "luna",   "brand": "LENOVO"},
        {"name": "luna",   "brand": "IPHONE"},
        {"name": "luna",   "brand": "SAMSUNG"},
]
```

As you can see, I have iterated the list base on how many the brands are.

For rizal since i have 3 brands it will became 3 rows, for luna i have 3 brands also so it will be 3 rows

Here is what i tried

```
foreach ($list as $key => $value) {
    if($value->name == 'rizal')
    {
        foreach ($brands as $key => $brand) {
            if($value->brand != $brand)
            {
                $new_arr['name'] = 'rizal';
                $new_arr['brand'] = $brand;
                $list[]=$new_arr;
            }
        }
    }
    if($value->name == 'luna')
    {
        foreach ($brands as $key => $brand) {
            if($value->brand != $brand)
            {
                $new_arr['name'] = 'luna';
                $new_arr['brand'] = $brand;
                $list[]=$new_arr;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but i cant get my desired output.

Comment: If you just want all combinations of name and brand, you can just get the unique names from the database and then combine it with the brands.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution to make a combination of names and brands as you are trying to make.

```
$json = '[
    {"name": "rizal",  "brand": "LENOVO"},
    {"name": "luna",   "brand": "IPHONE"}
]';

$brands = ['LENOVO', 'IPHONE', 'SAMSUNG'];

$list = json_decode( $json, true );
$names = array_column( $list, 'name');

$combination = [];

foreach ($names as $name) {
    foreach ($brands as $brand ) {
        $combination [] = [ "name" => $name, "brand" => $brand ]; 
    }
}

$encoded = json_encode( $combination );
var_dump($encoded);
```